# how to cope with different type of xml

Tags: xml, go, podcast

I am writing a podcast application just as a weekend project. Just few minutes after starting I ran into an issue. So far I've looked at xml for two feeds.

1. http://feeds.feedburner.com/coderradiomp3?format=xml
2. http://feeds.twit.tv/sn.xml
3. http://revision3.com/tekzilla/feed/mp4-hd30/

In both cases link to mp3 files are are at different locations. In  feed#2 it is under item -> link where as in feed # 1 it is under item -> media:content

Similarly channel -> link in feed # 2 is url to feed's xml where as in feed  # 1 it is a link to the web site.

so far I am just comparing feeds from two sites. there is a possibility that some other site is generating feed is some other way.

Now because link to mp3 are/can be in different locations in feeds. how can I reliably parse feeds to always find link to mp3, title, pub date, etc all the time.

Is it because one is rss and other is atom?
How will I know which one is what. Both feed # 2 and feed # 3 starts with rss, but have links to media file at different location.

Comment: The standard XML parser in Go can tolerate missing fields.  How "variable" are the XML documents that you are considering?  Is there a format that you can consider that represents the superset of the kinds of documents you'll be reading?

Comment: Specifically, can you revise your question to *concretely* express which podcast formats you're talking about?  `RSS` and `Atom`?  The details matter here.  You might also look at the docs in https://github.com/gpodder/podcastparser/blob/master/doc/index.rst to see what other developers have considered in terms of what fields are interesting specifically for podcasts.

Answer (score 0):

Self promotion: https://github.com/kylewolfe/simplexml

This xml package is better suited for dynamic xml manipulation (imo). It's currently in development but I've used it for a few non critical tools so far.